AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights - Filter Records by JSON filters
I have cloudwatch log where json object protocol_headers is flattened as below:
protocol_headers.0.header_name  test
protocol_headers.0.header_value test
protocol_headers.1.header_name  test 1
protocol_headers.1.header_value test 1

I have to fetch the header_value where header_name is test 1. I have tried various option using parse but not able to get to work.
Assistance is much appreciated. Thank you
